# Why did my tkinter text entry disappear suddenly?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

So I want this Tkinter entry but I can't find it what am I doing wrong?

```
import tkinter as tk
import math
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

exit_button = tk.Button(root, text = "Exit", command = root.destroy)
exit_button.place(x=1506, y=0)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_entry = tk.Entry(root, width = 100, fg = "black").place()
frame.place(relx=.5,rely=.5, anchor='center')




root.mainloop()
```

I want to make the entry show, why is gone I did everything right?

Comment: do not use modules after class like that. do `main_entry.place()` in new line also place requires (I think) x and y coordinates

Comment: Just using `place()` is not enough, you have to supply a `x` and `y` argument to it, `place(x=10,y=20)`.

Answer (score 0):

here, put layout options on variables like this (if You want to just place a widget somewhere use `.pack` which also does not necessarily require arguments):

```
import tkinter as tk
import math
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

exit_button = tk.Button(root, text = "Exit", command = root.destroy)
exit_button.place(x=1506, y=0)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_entry = tk.Entry(root, width = 100, fg = "black")
main_entry.place(x=50, y=50)
frame.place(relx=.5,rely=.5, anchor='center')

root.mainloop()
```